# Number of cliques or anti-cliques using Ramsey Theorem

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorics, probability-theory

By Ramsey theorem, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $R(k,k) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $G=(V,E)$ is a graph with $|V| > R(k,k)$ vertices, then $G$ must contain a clique or an independent set (anti-clique).
Now, I wish to formulate something similar but with a guarantee on the number of cliques\independent sets. I have in my mind the following statement: if $G=(V,E)$ is a graph with $|V| > mR(k,k)$ vertices, then $G$ has at least $\frac{R(k,k)(m-1)}{k}$ cliques\independent set: it has at least one (by the original Ramsey theorem), remove it and get a graph with $mR(k,k)-k$ vertices - and again apply the real theorem until the graph has less vertices then $R(k,k)$.

My questions are:

1. Is this statement correct? I believe so but afraid of silly mistakes.
2. Are there tighter bounds on the number of cliques/independent sets?

Comment: As a graph theory question, I think this is ontopic here. It would also fit on [math.SE], though; where do you want it?

Comment: This sounds like a pure math question to me, without any obvious relation to computation.  Is there some reason this is best answered from a computer science perspective?  that this is especially relevant or of interest to the CS community?  While pure math questions aren't necessarily off-topic here, it helps to articulate the connection to computer science.  Can you edit your question accordingly, or flag it for migration to [Math.SE] if you think it's a better fit there?  (But don't duplicate-post it on two sites.)